# Import XML into R

Tags: r, xml, import

I am trying to import an xml file into R and convert it to a data frame, but am having trouble grabbing the different nodes. Many of the nodes have characters in them (ex: ") so I am having a hard time specifying them to be pulled out. I also am not completely clear how to pull out lower levels of the nodes as a I move down the hierarchy.

I am using `xmlParse` and `xmlToDataFrame`

```
doc <- xmlParse("http://www.orphadata.org/data/xml/en_product6.xml")
doc2 <-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//Disorder"))[c("OrphaNumber")]

#this works but when I try to add more nodes with unusual characters or lower levels it fails. 

doc3 <-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//Disorder"))[c("OrphaNumber","Name lang="en"")]

#or when I try to grab a lower node
doc4 <-xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//Disorder"))[c("OrphaNumber","/DisorderGeneAssociation")]
```

expected results are

```
head(doc3)
OrphaNumber   Name lang="en"
166024        Multiple epiphyseal dysplasia,
166035        Brachydactyly-short stature-retinitis pigmentosa syndrome


head(doc4)
OrphaNumber   DisorderGeneAssociationStatus

166024        <SourceOfValidation>22587682[PMID]
166035        <SourceOfValidation>28285769[PMID]</SourceOfValidation>
```

Comment: Please include sample XML in body of question. URL contains no XML.

Comment: Instead of wrapping your desired text in `""` use `''`

Comment: oops sorry added the xml--thanks!

Comment: That is a very large XML. Please post a *sample* version, preferably in the body of your question in case web links change.